# Javascript \n is not working and browser still loading after result print

Tags: javascript

I have two issues here:

1) \r\n is not working, but if I'm using `<br>` then it's working
2) After initializing the funtion and printing the desired output, my browser is still loading. I think I didn't define my loop correctly.

Where is my mistake?

```js
function checkNumber(){

 var myNumber = document.getElementById("userNumber").value;
 alert(myNumber);

 for (var i=0; i < myNumber; i++ ){
  document.write("I love javascript" + "\r\n" + "<br>");
 }
 
}
```

```html
<h2>
 Print text matter in single line as per number entered in input type filed
</h2>
<input type="text" id="userNumber">
<input type="submit" onclick="checkNumber()">
```

Comment: Whitespace (including line breaks) is generally collapsed into single spaces in HTML. Also using `document.write()` after the page has loaded will cause the whole page to be cleared and overwritten with new content.

Answer (score 0):

It could very well be an order of precedence issue. I have your code working on my Chrome and Mozilla browsers on Windows (althrough \r\n makes it work on Linux and Windows).

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<h2>
 Print text matter in single line as per number entered in input type filed
</h2>
<input type="text" id="userNumber">
<input type="submit" onclick="checkNumber()">


</body>
<script>

function checkNumber(){

 var myNumber = document.getElementById("userNumber").value;
 alert(myNumber);

 for (var i=0; i < myNumber; i++ ){
  document.write("I love javascript" + "\r\n" + "<br>");
 }
 
}

</script>
</html>
```